# Upcasting to a generic object from system.object

Tags: c#, generics, .net-2.0

I have some simple code which demonstrates my problem:

```
private void InitializeOther()
{
  List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();
  Casting(list);
}

//in the "real" case I have no knowledge of o, other than it could be a List<>
private void Casting(object o)
{
  Type t = o.GetType();
  while (t.BaseType != typeof(Object))
  {
    if (t.IsGenericType && typeof(List<>) == t.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
    {
      //now I know that o is of type List<>. How can I now access List<> members from o?
      break;
    }
    t = t.BaseType;
  }
}
```

So, I can be sure that object o is of (or derived) from `List<T>`, but now I want to be able to access `List<T>` members on o, which means casting it up to `List<Foo>`. In my "real" case, I have no knowledge of Foo.

I'm pretty sure it can be done and if you know how to do it I'd be very grateful if you could share your knowledge with me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small hack will be to try and cast `o` to a non-generic `IList`, since `List<T>` implements both generic and non-generic interfaces. The same can be said of `Collection<T>` which is the most used base class for user collections.

If this is not an option, you can always get along with reflective method invocation (late binding): `MethodInfo.Invoke()`, etc.